# AS3 changing x value of a parent doesn't apply the x-change to its children?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

So basicly I have a class which adds items and needs a drag and drop. I change the x value of the entire contianer class simply by this.x = something

By drag and drop all the items slide across the screen. When I trace the x value of the container class it has changed, but the x value of the items stayed the same (although their x value on the screen definitely changed). Anyone have some tips on this one?

Thanks!

Comment: the children have the same x position within their container. the value doesn't change because you're tracing the local coordinates, not the global ones. Have a look at localToGloabal()(http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#localToGlobal()) You could to also manually get the absolute position by adding the container's position to the item's position, or could check the transform matrix: container.item.transform.concatenatedMatrix.tx / ty respectively

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. For the moment I change the x value of the items in a for-loop. But I'll look into that hoping to avoid going through that loop every time I drag and drop the items.

Answer (score 0):

```
var childActualX : Number = container.x + child.x;
```